# vba, error message, vba references, regex

Tags: regex, vba

I am getting an error message.

```
    Compile error: Method or data member not found
    Line causing Error: It highlights Sub Macro1() and after I click ok, it selects: .MultiLine = 
    I just saved it as a macro enabled workbook. Now getting: Compile error. Method or data member not found. Error goes to same place.
```

Why is the code receiving this error message? I am using the VBA references: Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0 and Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5. I am using VBA since I need to use Regex on my spreadsheet. I need to change anything like 3_CELL_VALUE or 2_CELL_VALUE to 1_CELL_VALUE to accurately count my data.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[0-9]_CELL_VALUE"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "1_CELL_VALUE"
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Set Myrange = Worksheets("Data").Range("$A$1:$A$9999")
    For Each cell In Myrange
        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = cell.Value
            With regEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With
            If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
                MsgBox (regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))
            Else
                MsgBox ("Not matched")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: If you added the reference to the Regex library, it should work.

Comment: It highlights Sub Macro1() and after I click ok, it selects: .MultiLine =.

Comment: There are two references that you can add involving regular expressions. Are you sure that you have included the right one (version 5.5)?

Comment: I am using Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 1.0
and Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two versions of the library `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions`, 1.0 and 5.5. The error message that you are getting shows that you are using the older 1.0 version. Swap it out for the newer version. *Don't* use `1.0` at all. The order in which you added the references might have caused the earlier version to hide the newer version.